# Fill Trix Editor with value from database

Tags: laravel

Right now, I'm coding a **edit blog article page**.

I'm following this documentation:
https://github.com/amaelftah/laravel-trix#render-trix-for-existing-model

I have $blogposting filled from database which stores all attributes about this blogposting. E.g.:

```
$blogposting->id
$blogposting->author_id
$blogposting->title
$blogposting->content
```

I want my trix-editor to get filled with `$blogposting->content`

What do I need to do to achieve this?

`@trix($blogposting, 'content')` does not work!

Thank you!

EDIT: The output of `dd($blogposting)` shows this:

```
App\Blogposting {#1299 ▼
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "blogpostings"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:10 [▼
    "id" => 27
    "blogcategory_id" => 1
    "url" => "2021-02-test-test-test-8"
    "user_id" => 1
    "title" => "Title Tile"
    "opener" => "Content Opener"
    "opener_picture" => "frq6f0QAPheya0Rue3uD4e9OXswytYj7fhXf6iWh.jpeg"
    "content" => "<div>test test test test</div>"
    "created_at" => "2021-05-02 20:55:30"
    "updated_at" => "2021-05-02 20:55:30"
  ]
  #original: array:10 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #savedTrixFields: []
  #savedAttachments: []
}
```

As you can see, content is in there: `"content" => "<div>test test test test</div>"`

Comment: did you followed the installation guide and put       
  @trixassets
in the head tag?

Comment: Yes, I included @trixassets in the head tag. Do I see it correctly that ```$blogposting``` should be a collection and ```'content'``` is the name of the textarea field? How can I debug this? I'm not sure if I am passing the correct variables.

Comment: {!! $blogposting->trix('content') !!}

Comment: try the above code instead of @trix($blogposting, 'content')

Comment: Ahmed, thank you, this was the solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

[According to documentation](https://github.com/amaelftah/laravel-trix#render-trix-for-existing-model)
there are multiple ways to render trix for already existing model

```
<!-- inside view blade file -->
@trix(\App\Post::class, 'content') // where Post is your model

@trix($blogposting, 'content')

{!! $blogposting->trix('content') !!} //must use HasTrixRichText trait in order for $model->trix() method work

{!! app('laravel-trix')->make($blogposting, 'content') !!}
```